# Show Only Favorite Tags Option

Tags: discussion

After some time using StackOverflow it became clearly that it's difficult to browse the tremendous amount of questions that users posts.

The main reason for this is because there are so many posts tagged with subjects that are not interesting to me and filtering all those questions takes lots of time.

There's an option in prefs to disable showing "Ignored Tags", but that makes me add a lot of ignoreg tags to tag list to work.

It would be great if I could set "Show Only Favorite Tags" in StackOverflow. Do you agree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [Stack Exchange filters (formerly known as "tag sets")](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/tag-sets-on-stack-exchange/).

[image: Screenshot of a new filter]

Filters allow you to keep track of questions with particular tags not just on Stack Overflow, but *across the entire Stack Exchange network*. [Create a new filter](https://stackexchange.com/filters/new) or [browse the popular ones](https://stackexchange.com/filters/popular) and try the feature out for yourself!

By way of example, [this filter](https://stackexchange.com/filters/19822/favorite-tags) shows all Stack Overflow questions tagged [objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c), [xcode](/questions/tagged/xcode), [xcode4](/questions/tagged/xcode4), [xcode4.2](/questions/tagged/xcode4.2), [iphone](/questions/tagged/iphone), [cocoa](/questions/tagged/cocoa), [ios](/questions/tagged/ios), [ipad](/questions/tagged/ipad), and [core-data](/questions/tagged/core-data).